# UnsupportedOperation: seek in reading excel files from zip file

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to read different excel files from one zip file.Please suggest a solution to the error or an alternative method.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for zip_file in glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/file.zip"):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    for f in zf.namelist():
      print(f)
      #f=f.replace('XLSX','xlsx')
      print(zf.open(f))
      dfs=pd.read_excel(zf.open(f)) 
      df = pd.concat([df,dfs],ignore_index=True)
```

The following code gives error:
**UnsupportedOperation: seek**

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading just one .zip file, you will not need `glob.glob`.

#### Edit:

Just tried your code, and it works, too. As a side note, it might be good to use the `pd.concat()` only once for a list of pandas.DataFrames, since currently it is creating new pandas dataframe each time, and allocating memory over and over again.

```py
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("files.zip")
for f in zf.namelist():
    if not f.lower().endswith(".xlsx"):
        continue
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(zf.open(f)))

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```